# How to watch my Thread variable from Main class?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have that code:

Main class:

```
public class myTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   try {
        Thread t1 = new myThreadClass("thread 1");
        t1.start();
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(glownyTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(glownyTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }  

 }
}
```

My Thread class

```
public class myThreadClass extends Thread {

private HashSet<String> texts = new HashSet<String>();

public myThreadClass(String id) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {}

@Override
public void run() {
     ... collecting Strings into my hashSet ....
}

public HashSet<String> getTexts() {
    return texts;
}
}
```

My Thread class is watching for network traffic, so I just cant call once

```
t1.getTexts()
```

whenever I want, because my hashSet can be empty (there are delays and latency in this network). How can I watch this texts hashSet and when some String will be added into hashSet - I i want my MAIN CLASS know about it? I just want to watch my Thread resources from Main class in smart way :)

If it will still be empty after my thread timeout, I want to know about it too.

Comment: You could use the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: How do you add values to your texts??

Comment: texts.add() in my Run() function in myThreadClass :) It monitors my network traffic

Answer (score 0):

You can use condition variables for this. Try something like:

```
class Monitor {

    private final ConcurrentMap<String,String> data = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>();
    private final Object mutex = new Object();

    /* Private to the monitoring thread. Wakes up other
     * threads, which may be waiting for data to arrive 
     */

    public void addElement(String key) {
        data.put(key, key);
        synchronized (mutex) { mutex.notifyAll(); }
    }

    public void removeElement(String key) {
        data.remove(key);
        synchronized (mutex) { mutex.notifyAll(); }
    }

    public Set<String> getElements() {
        return data.keySet();
    }

    /* Can be called from any thread. Will wait at most "timeout"
     * milliseconds
     */

    public boolean waitForChanges(long timeout) throws InterruptedException {

        final long then = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout;
        long left = timeout;

        synchronized (mutex) {

            while (data.isEmpty() && left > 0) {

                mutex.wait(left);
                left = then - System.currentTimeMillis();
            }

            return !data.isEmpty();
        }
    }
}

class MonitoringTask extends Runnable {

    private final Monitor monitor;

    MonitoringTask(Monitor m) {
        this.monitor = m;
    }  

    public void run() {

        while (true) {

            if (somethingHasHappened()) {

                monitor.addElement("foo");
            }
        }
    }
}

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Monitor monitor = new Monitor();
        final MonitoringTask task = new MonitoringTask(monitor);
        final Thread thread = new Thread(task);

        thread.setName("Monitor Thread");
        thread.start();

        if (monitor.waitForChanges(1500)) {

            final Set<String> elts = monitor.getElements();
            ...

        } else {

            // Time-out
        }
    }
}
```

(I haven't tried to present this to a Java compiler, so watch out for all kinds of mistakes).

Comment: So how can I Use WaitForChanges from my main class?